# How to remove length range indicator from a TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

If you set **maxLength** to be of non-null value, a small length range indicator will appear below the **TextField**. How can such indicator be hidden or removed?

Answer (score 3):

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    counterText: '', 
  ),
),
```